# Rename folders in MATLAB which contain many files takes too much time

Tags: matlab, batch-rename

I was using MATLAB to rename ~100 folders. I knew that:

```
movefile(old_folder_path,new_folder_path)
```

can work. But this time it's taking ~1 minute at least to rename one folder. I assume that each of my folder contains ~20000 images which in total are about 1G.

But manually rename the folder is as quick as renaming empty folders. Can any one tell me what was going on and if there is some other work-around?

Comment: Did you really rename that folder? Maybe you just moved it into another one?

Answer (score 3):

If this is so much faster in the shell, use a shell command:

```
if ispc
   cmd = 'move';
else
   cmd = 'mv';
end
cmd = [cmd,' ',old_folder_path,' ',new_folder_path];
system(cmd);
```

The MATLAB command [`system`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) executes a shell command in the default shell. On Windows this is `cmd.exe`, and on UNIX-like systems (Mac and Linux) it's given by the `$MATLAB_SHELL` or `$SHELL` environment variable (checked in that order, if neither exists it uses `/bin/sh`).

The command executed here is equivalent to whatever OP refers to as "manually rename", since any file manager GUI (such as Windows explorer) will run the same underlying system functions.

My guess is that MATLAB creates the new directory and moves files one by one.

Comment: Please, specify what kind of shell, platform are you talking about?

Comment: @RedEyed: I've updated the answer with a bit of explanation. The code above *shoud* work on any version of MATLAB, and on any platform supported by MATLAB.

Comment: @Cris Luengo.  This works very well, many thanks. I tried on one smaller folder that contains 24000 images (700M), compared to **26 seconds** of time consumption using MATLAB _movefile_, the shell command used **0.7 second**

Comment: @DidasW: Thanks for adding proper timing! I really suspect that `movefile` is poorly implemented... :)

Comment: @DidasW: Is that under Windows? I’ve never seen such a message on Linux or MacOS. Does `[~,~]=system(...)` suppress this message?

Comment: @CrisLuengo After trial, it doesn't suppress the message in Matlab2018a and Windows7

Comment: @DidasW: What was that message again? I don't remember what this was about, and the comment is no longer there.